# Why does 'only tagging a question' always result in a 'rejected edit'?

Tags: support, tags

I am new at trying to participate in SE. My interest in doing so is in the area of charting and/or reporting in Drupal, because it matches my background, and the modules I (co-) maintain.

So I started with searching for questions about 'chart'. I noticed the [charts] tag in some of them! But also quite a few which are for sure about charts not using that tag. So I added the charts tag as a suggested edit. I did so for about 5 or 7 questions, but ALL such edits got rejected! Even worse: because of all these rejections, at some point I was not allowed to do any more edits. How nice! ... And frustrating ...

Therefor I have these questions:

1. Why does 'only tagging a question' always result in a 'rejected edit'?
2. What can I do to 'withdraw' my rejected edits? E.g. because in the meantime I have an accepted suggested edit of the very same question in which I ALSO suggested to add a tag ... the very same charts tag. Which doesn't seem to overrule/replace the prior rejected edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does 'only tagging a question' always result in a 'rejected edit'?

AFAIK, there is no site rule that reviewers should always reject 'only tagging a question' edits. However, one of the preset grounds for rejection is that the edit is not "substantial" enough, and it may be that a number of reviewers feel that only adding a tag falls in that category.

> What can I do to 'withdraw' my rejected edits?

AFAIK, this is not possible.  Also: A reviewer cannot withdraw a "reject" if he discovers that he made a mistake.  Most actions on this site "stick" (you can change you up/down votes, but only in a fairly limited timespan).

Comment: Thank you 'Free Radical', you answers help to learn how to become a better participant. However, wouldn't you agree that for people (like me, native Flemish speaking) who did-not-learn-English-on-their-mother's-knee', it should not be needed to use a dictionary or something similar to at least understand every word/abbreviation used in every question, answer, comment. Such as in this case: who or what is AFAIK!?!? Does it have to do with a "maverick" (whatever that may be ...)?

Comment: I just read some other question that also mentioned that AFAIK-thing. In that question a translation of it to "As Far As I Know" could work as a possible translation. So I returned to this reply, and indeed. Here it also "might" fit. Am I close with my translation? IMHO (Oeps, I now also start doing it !!!) it might ...

Comment: Yup, it means "As Far As I Know".  It is not really English, but an initialism popular among hackers. Here is a handy list: http://www.travelmole.com/news_feature.php?id=1117491